# Modify Link List

Tags: xslt

When I add

```
  <table >   
      <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match='Row'>
     <tr>
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="@URLwMenu" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:template>
```

,nothing appears. How can I use URLwMenu Field Ref with xslt?

**Edited:**
I found this answer but it only shows URL not the description. I don't want the urls appear. The descriptions of the URLs have to appear.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/bs-Cyrl-BA/sharepointfr/thread/8a368e8f-459e-496e-925e-298810d3184b

```
  <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' ...>
       <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Row">
      <li> 
         <xsl:element name="a">
              <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@URLwMenu"/></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="@URL"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </li>  
  </xsl:template>
```

I think I have to put something else instead of 'dsQueryResponse'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the actual hyperlink use @URL
For the description use @URL.desc

```
<a href="{@URL}><xsl:value-of select="@URL.desc" /></a>
```

Hope this helps

Dave